# Why is it [down-votes] questions on Meta are primarily downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, meta

This just simply seems completely crazy and ironic in my opinion. I look at the first page of questions for the tag [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) and find that only three (in my last count) were voted >10. I'm just curious as to what drives this (no right or wrong...just opinions here).

Comment: I helped unsolve the unsolved non-problem by voting this down.

Comment: I never stated that this was really a problem. It was looking for opinions.

Comment: Ok… why does anybody care?

Comment: The obvious solution is to then tag every one of your questions with [up-votes].

Comment: @BoltClock LOL...maybe I should start considering it ;)

Comment: *Primarily* downvoted? That's a bit of a baseless claim. Sure, there aren't very many questions here on MSO because it's a new site, but still. There are 24 questions with that tag, only 11 of them with a negative score (3 of those from you). **That's less than half.** And on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/down-votes), those stats are 337 out of 1151, which is just under 30% of them. Where do you get "primarily" from?

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. At first, I thought people were just trying to be funny, giving down-vote questions a lot of down votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions in the [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) tag are often downvoted because the community disagrees with the suggestions put forth in the questions. Not *all* questions with the [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) tag are bad, but sometimes those asking questions ask them because they feel wronged by the votes, and the community simply disagrees with them and thinks the status quo is fine. If there is a suggestion that the community likes, though, surely they will upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

I would put this in a comment, as I don't think this is actually an answer, but reputation is not currently sufficient to do anything but post questions and answers, which I find frustrating. If this is a big no-no, I apologize in advance.

Anyway, I don't want to sound harsh or anything, but just because almost all of your questions and answers have been downvoted does not imply there is a problem in the system. I mean no offense, but it is most likely something that you are doing that is prompting repeated downvotes.

I feel I should also add that opinion-request/discussion questions are a general not-supposed-to-do-that thing on Stack Overflow. I've actually looked into this somewhat extensively, and it would be a good idea to stick to more solid, answerable questions. That might in fact be, in part at least, what brings you your downvotes.

I hope this helps a bit.

Peace!

Comment: Check out [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253467). Also, I will bring up the fact that there doesn't seem to be a good area to ask about opinions, even on the Meta, apparently.

Comment: All of the related links that people gave in the comments that related directly to downvoting as an issue in and of itself had enough downvotes themselves to indicate that the community as a whole does not agree that it is an issue at all.

Comment: The fact that there have apparently been many other similar posts yet nothing has ever been done about it also implies that the general user populace does not find it a problem.

Comment: Relevant question about this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253471/2693146

Comment: You should start researching your questions before you ask them. I have noticed you asking multiple questions that have already been gone over extensively, even in the past few days.

Comment: Start flagging them to close them. I'll start with this one.