# Where is the best place to ask a subjective, MSO-specific question?

Tags: support, meta, questions

This is asking for a simple answer regarding where the best place for subjective discussion about a *Meta* Stack Overflow-specific topic. This question exists for the sole reason of apparently Meta Stack Overflow isn't the place to discuss subjective matters regarding the Meta Stack Overflow site (Ex. [A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253469/2693146), [B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252237/2693146)). This question itself is *not* intended to be subjective in of itself - if it doesn't have a clear-cut answer, then that's an obvious issue.

**EDIT:** My question is that of *where* should this be discussed: chat.stackoverflow.com, etc.

(Side note: this might really be a question for MSE, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: This has also been asked and answered numerous times.  Would you PLEASE attempt to search a bit before posting questions one after the other?

Comment: Link to said similar dup, please?

Comment: Find it yourself.  If you keep posting FAQs, I'm afraid nobody would bother to point to the relevant resources.

Comment: @devnull I meant the Meta, not the regular site. Sorry.

Comment: @devnull I meant for MSO, not SO.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off-topic for MSO too: _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: @devnull I was asking for where the best location *would* be. I can tell it is not here.

Comment: @impinball doesn't look like the duplicate is actually a duplicate since you are asking about MSO, but it's not quite clear what you mean.  Generalities are difficult.  Can you provide specific examples of what you want to ask?  But in general, guideline questions on Meta sites (MSE, plus all of the per-site Metas including MSO) are much more relaxed so questions that invite opinion-based answers, as long as the question itself is on-topic, tend to be more accepted.

Comment: @impinball  I'm guessing [Why is it 'down-votes' questions on Meta are primarily downvoted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253460/why-is-it-down-votes-questions-on-meta-are-primarily-downvoted) is the sole reason for asking this question.  The reason it was closed as "primarily opinion-based answers" is because there is no way any reasonably person could provide an answer to that because (1) the premise in which you based you question was flawed  and (2) no one can explain why someone else downvoted so there really isn't a way to provide an answer that isn't a complete guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Feature request: Opinon-based site for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252444/feature-request-opinon-based-site-for-stack-overflow) and other questions I have seen in the past few days, the unfortunate answer is that there simply is no such place associated with SO or MSO. Apparently it was attempted before, but it didn't work out ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

So many ways to answer your question.

- "The close reason *...but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* is weird". Yep, it is. You're gonna see opinion, we're not describing the proper usage of the coalesce function. Your [exhibit B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252237/why-is-primarily-opinion-based-a-valid-close-reason-on-meta) is a better platform to approach this (I agree with [Pekka's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252237/why-is-primarily-opinion-based-a-valid-close-reason-on-meta#comment7021_252237)).
- "[Where's Meta.Meta.StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-about-meta-meta-stack-overflow)" Here. Well, here, or [Meta.StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) if you're talking about issues more network-wide, or chat. But, mostly, here.
- "My questions on Meta keep getting downvoted." Yes, they do. You've got an [unpopular feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253452/suggestions-to-help-fix-some-confusing-downvote-issues) (downvotes on feature requests are [valid and noble](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), and you hadn't really proposed anything there), and a [couple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253460/why-is-it-down-votes-questions-on-meta-are-primarily-downvoted) of [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253467/are-the-downvotes-a-problem-in-stack-overflow) that seem to flow from confusion around how your first question was received. And this one. So, well, my *opinion* is to start fresh. Votes are thrown around pretty freely here, and since the recent [Great Meta Split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014), votes here mean jack all. Leave it behind you, have a beer, and start over.